# Vue2 — Как подключить один плагин два раза но с разными настройками?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть плагин [vue2-storage](https://yarkovaleksei.github.io/vue2-storage/ru/) позволяющий использовать браузерный localStorage.

В настройках этого плагина можно указывать префикс, который будет использоваться для ключей.

В моем Vue приложении нужно хранить в localStorage два вида данных: пользователи и автомобили. Эти данные между собой никак не связаны и пересекаться не должны.

Пользователи - это список логинов как ключей и данные их профилей как значения:

```
evan {name: 'Evan', 'email': 'evan@mail.com'}
piter {name: 'Piter', 'email': 'piter@mail.com'}
eva {name: 'Eva', 'email': 'eva@mail.com'}
...
```

Автомобили - это список номеров авто как ключей и их характеристики как значения:

```
А111АА11 {brand: 'Volkswagen', 'model': 'Polo', 'year': 2015, hp: 150}
А222АА22 {brand: 'BMW', 'model': 'X3', 'year': 2017, hp: 170}
А333АА33 {brand: 'Lada', 'model': 'Priora', 'year': 2008, hp: 98}
...
```

Можно ли сделать что-то вроде этого:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Plugin } from 'vue2-storage';
Vue.use(Plugin, {prefix: 'users_'});
Vue.use(Plugin, {prefix: 'cars_'});

// И далее используем как то так:
this.$usersStorage.set(...);
this.$carsStorage.set(...);
...
```

Конечно код указанный выше не будет работать, потому что Vue не позволяет подключить два одинаковых плагина. Или как то все-таки позволяет?

Возможно есть какой-то обходной путь, в виде создания какого-то рода своих оберток над методами этого плагина?

Или вовсе создать два своих плагина, которые будут наследоваться от vue2-storage, но хранить себя во Vue приложении не просто как this.$storage, а как this.$usersStorage и this.$carsStorage?

Понимаю что хранения JSON объектов в localStorage это не совсем верный подход, и для этого более подходящий вариант возможно IndexedDB. Но данных будет очень мало, всего около 10 записей, и использовать для них более развесистый IndexedDB не очень хочется.

Comment: А зачем Вам хранить 2 разных записи, когда Вы можете хранить одну и подзывать только нужное свойство c массивом под решаемую задачу, а не всё сразу? И второе, почему не Vuex + vuex-presist?

Comment: Насчет плагинов точно не скажу без примера в вoпросе (ибо ленив), но с директивами работает такое: `Vue.options.directives.FooCopy = Vue.options.directives.Foo; delete Vue.options.directives.Foo; Vue.options.directives.FooCopy.name = 'd-foo-copy'; Vue.directive('Foo', Foo);` (эти манипуляции предполагаются в main.js перед `new Vue`). Таким образом я в реальном проекте заменял встроенную в микрофреймворк директиву своей кастомной, сохранив их обе. С плагинами тот же принцип должен работать по идее, только имена свойств конечно будут другие (глянь есть ли свойство `plugins` в `Vue.options`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного не по сути вопроса, но для решения задачи хорошо подошли Vuex + vuex-persistedstate.